# How display the image of bitmap in ImageView using BitmapFactory.Options?

Tags: android, android-bitmap

i follow the steps in developers.android.com in best practice for Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently, but i cant let the video thumbnail image apear in the imageview, what is the problem?

```
holder.imageHolder.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(
                    aListData.get(position).path, 130, 100));

    public Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(String path,
            int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth,
                reqHeight);

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
    }

    public int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options,
            int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

            final int halfHeight = height / 2;
            final int halfWidth = width / 2;

            // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2
            // and keeps both
            // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
            while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                    && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
                inSampleSize *= 2;
            }
        }

        return inSampleSize;
    }
```

If it came from the developers.android.com it should work but i follow the guide but it didn't work. 
reference: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: This code looks ok, problem is somewhere else. Do some checks. Maybe decodeSampledBitmapFromResource returns null?

Comment: what do you mean decodeSampledBitmapFromResource returns null? my target is return a bitmap decodefile from path using bitmapfactory.options, in the site developers.com all needed how to return bitmap efficiently is in that page but i followed it nothing happens

Comment: I understand what you are trying to do. But maybe there is a problem during bitmap decoding process and that's why you should check if the return value of decodeSampledBitmapFromResource is Bitmap or null.

Comment: i put condition its null, how come its null when i already decodeFile from it? How to solve it?

Comment: My guess is that you've provided incorrect path. Check if a call to aListData.get(position).path returns correct path to a bitmap.

Comment: the path is correct,  i use MediaStore same path gives me an videoThumbnail but in this style without using mediastore only using path to get the imagebitmap i cannot make it visible the image of the video